# Hive: remove the special characters and keep the space between the word

Tags: regex, string, hive, space

[image]

I have custom table and there are special characters in this column. I want to remove the special characters and keep the space between the word.

I try this query.

select customer_ID, REGEXP_REPLACE(name, '[^0-9A-Za-z]', '') from customer

But this query removes all special characters and space.

How can I special characters and keep the space between the word in this column?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to keep the whitespaces then you could add that to the negated character class.

To match the character class one or more times you  could add the + sign after the character class.

[`[^0-9A-Za-z ]+`](https://regex101.com/r/fcp8yz/2)

Your query would look like:

`select customer_ID, REGEXP_REPLACE(name, '[^0-9A-Za-z ]+', '') from customer`

Comment: select customer_ID, REGEXP_REPLACE(name, '[^0-9A-Za-z ]+', '') from customer

I get error message Invalid function 'EGEXP_REPLACE'

Comment: Invalid function `'EGEXP_REPLACE'`. Is that a typo? Can you try your original code and only add a whitespace in the character class?

Comment: Hi, The fourth Bird, could you update the whole query and I will accept it as the answer. select customer_ID, REGEXP_REPLACE(name, '[^0-9A-Za-z ]+', '') from customer

Comment: @Anson Assuming that `select customer_ID, REGEXP_REPLACE(name, '[^0-9A-Za-z ]+', '') from customer` worked for you, I have added it to my answer.